# If you have One-to-One-Mapping of Kernel- and User-Threads, why isn't process be blocked, if it makes a system-call?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, system-calls

I often read that when you have many-to-one-mapping, a sys-call would block the whole process, but a one-to-one would'nt. But why? The Thread that makes the sys-call is blocked anyway and can't make a switch-command to the other user-thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel schedules the threads not the processes globally.
In a very general case when a process is made of just its main thread, we use a kind of shortcut in the manner of speaking and say that the kernel schedules those processes, but it is just a (very common) corner case.

Each thread can have its own priority, its own affinity to some CPUs...
But by default these properties are inherited from the main thread in the process it belongs to, and if we don't change them explicitly, we can have the illusion that all these threads inside a single process form one single entity from the scheduler point of view; but it is not the case.

When one thread is blocked on a system call for example, this does not prevent the other threads from being run.
The blocked thread does not decide of anything concerning the next thread to be run (except if we explicitly build a dedicated applicative synchronisation mechanism with cond-vars...).
The switch to another thread, in the same or another process, is entirely decided by the OS scheduler.

Another confusing situation for example is when a segmentation fault occurs in a thread.
Since the address space is shared between all the threads inside a single process, this is the process as a whole that must be terminated.
Then all its threads disappear at once, which gives again the illusion that all these threads form one single entity from the scheduler point of view; but it is more related to address space management than scheduling.

note: there may exist some user-space implementations of threads in which the OS scheduler have no way to consider these threads as distinct (it sees only the main thread of the process).
Depending on the internal details of such user-space implementations, a blocking system call could lead to blocking the entire process or not.
Nowadays, it is much more common to rely on the native threads provided by the kernel.

Comment: So you can say, if you have one-to-one-mapping, that the user-thread doen't need to switch to the next user-thread, because the kernel would notice this and execute a antoher user-thread associated with this process?

Comment: @LarsLafleur that's it, the user-space thread does not decide of anything concerning the next thread to be run (except if we explicitly build a dedicated applicative synchronisation mechanism with cond-vars...). The switch to another thread, in the same or another process, is entirely decided by the OS scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's one very specific thing that you're missing.

When you have a one-to-one mapping of user threads to kernel threads, that means that each user thread has its own kernel thread. There's no "switch-command to the other user thread" because the other user thread is another kernel thread, and it's the kernel's job to switch between kernel threads. On modern operating systems, the kernel can easily switch kernel threads when a thread is blocked in a system call.

When you have a many-to-one mapping of user threads, that means a single kernel thread is expected to run code for more than one user thread. Here, the user code has to do something to cause that same kernel thread to execute code for another user thread. It can't do that if it's blocked in a system call.